# Combining list datetime

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting the errror below. The code works fine when the count is 1 but when I use string.join and try to convert the StartDate I am getting this error?  Is there a better way to format this list?

`The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.`

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                List<Meeting> Meeting = new List<Meeting>();
                List<MeetingDates> ListOfMeetingDates = new List<MeetingDates>();
                ListOfMeetingDates.Add(new MeetingDates() { MeetingDatesId = 1, StartDate= "11-1-2020"});
                ListOfMeetingDates.Add(new MeetingDates() { MeetingDatesId = 2, StartDate = "11-2-2020" });
                ListOfMeetingDates.Add(new MeetingDates() { MeetingDatesId = 3, StartDate = "11-3-2020" });
                Meeting.Add(new Meeting() { Meetingid = 1, MeetingName="a",ListOfMeetingDates= ListOfMeetingDates });
                var listOfMeetings = Meeting
                    .Select(x => new MeetingViewModel
                    {
                        MeetingName = x.MeetingName,
                        MeetingDate = GetDateRangeFormatted(x.ListOfMeetingDates)
                     }).ToList();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.ToString();
            }
        }
        private static string GetDateRangeFormatted(IEnumerable<MeetingDates> meetingDates)
        {
            if (meetingDates.Count() == 0)
                return "";
            if (meetingDates.Count() == 1)
                return Convert.ToDateTime(meetingDates.First().StartDate).ToString("MMMM dd yyyy");
            return string.Join(" - ", Convert.ToDateTime(meetingDates.Select(d => d.StartDate).ToString()).ToString("MMMM dd yyyy"));
        }
        class Meeting
        {
            public int Meetingid { get; set; }
            public string MeetingName { get; set; }

            public List<MeetingDates> ListOfMeetingDates { get; set; }
        }
        class MeetingDates
        {
            public int MeetingDatesId { get; set; }
            public string StartDate { get; set; }
        }
        class MeetingViewModel
        {
            public string MeetingName { get; set; }
            public string MeetingDate { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: just now the system was built and I didnt want to change anything

Comment: Do not use Convert.ToDateTime.. and stop with all the string to date to string to date operations.. just make DateTimes, because "11-3-2020", is either 3rd of Nov or 11th of March depending on where the computer is, but `new DateTime(2020,3,11)` doesn't go wrong or depend on the culture setting.. it starts out as a datetime and can be thus all its life til you format it to string just before you display it

Comment: The problem is your `string.Join` line. The order in which you call `Convert.ToDateTime` vs `meetingDates.Select` is backwards. Is there any particular reason your date properties are `string` rather than `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset`?

Comment: I am not sure about the reason not I am not in a position to change it

Comment: Could you elaborate? Why can't you change it? Where does the data come from?

Comment: its coming from EF model I would need to change the database.

Comment: **The root of your problem is the parser can't convert your date string format.** Using DateTime internally avoids all of this. Avoid the final string format until you're ready to output or display. At that point you can use any string format you want. If you insist on storing and working on date strings then consider using an unambiguous standard format (such as ISO-8601).

Comment: You may need to write a custom parse method if you are locked to a particular format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change code from:

```
return string.Join(" - ", Convert.ToDateTime(meetingDates.Select(d => d.StartDate).ToString()).ToString("MMMM dd yyyy"));
```

To:

```
var dates = meetingDates.Select(d => new {dt = Convert.ToDateTime(d.StartDate).ToString("MMMM dd yyyy")}).ToList();
        return string.Join(" - ", dates.Select(s => s.dt));
```

It should work, but it would be better to use DateTime type for dates

Answer (score 0):

**The Short Answer**

This line:

```
return string.Join(" - ", Convert.ToDateTime(meetingDates.Select(d => d.StartDate).ToString()).ToString("MMMM dd yyyy"));
```

Should be written like this:

```
return string.Join(" - ", meetingDates.Select(d => Convert.ToDateTime(d.StartDate).ToString("MMMM dd yyyy")));
```

**Some Advice**

When debugging an error in a complex, composite statement like this, break it up into individual pieces. If you do that with your original statement, you get this:

```
var step1 = meetingDates.Select(d => d.StartDate);
var step2 = step1.ToString();
var step3 = Convert.ToDateTime(step2);
var step4 = step3.ToString("MMMM dd yyyy");
var step5 = string.Join(" - ", step4);  
return step5;
```

If the problem doesn't immediately pop out at you once you've done this, use the IntelliSense in VisualStudio to examine each step. In this case, note that the type of `step1` is an `IEnumerable<string>`. When you call `ToString` on that, you get the string "System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectListIterator`2[UserQuery+MeetingDates,System.String]". When you pass that value to `Convert.ToDateTime` you get an exception.

**The Long Answer**

As mentioned in several comments, you really want to avoid working with dates in strings if possible. When working with dates, you may need to be aware of the locale/culture. For example, "11-3-2020" can mean "November 3, 2020" or "March 11, 2020", depending on locale. When working with times, you also need to take the time zone into account.

It will help to be more aware of the big picture. The data you're working with was originally created by something and placed in a database. Ideally you would want to convert and store the dates so that they are represented in your EF model as binary `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset`. If you really have no control over that, then the better way to convert strings to dates is with [DateTime.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-5.0) or [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0).